# Show full URL on Google Search results?

Tags: google-search

I would like to see the full URL disclosed. Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe using a custom script or browser extension?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a Chrome extension that makes almost this, but it is needed to hover the mouse over the google result:

- [Chrome Store: Link Revealer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-revealer/nphhadgebjlmcfleikmiedhohdfbfoin)

[image: Example of how the extension works: the same google search of OP with the full url floating when hover the pointer at the google result.]

Answer (score 2):

This userscript does that: [Google Search restore URLs (undo breadcrumbs)](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/389751-google-search-restore-urls-undo-breadcrumbs)